# How to find the frequency of elements in two dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to find the frequency of each element in the two dimensional array. Can anyone help me with the code.

Comment: What you have tried so far, please post code and where you are facing issues?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. For the community to best help you, and remembering that this is not a code-writing service, it is important to identify what experiments/research you have done so far and why none of that helped. Also it is essential that you tag your question with the appropriate programming language.

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question? At least, state in which language are you trying it out or wish to do so. There are a gazillion languages which could be used to do this and only one or two which you intend to use. So, please do edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm using c language and i have a big 2D array with different values..  I need to find frequency of each element in it.

Comment: Okay Akbar, check my answer and accept it if it works. Else, do tell me if you need any modifications in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are an absolute beginner in programming. Assuming you are using a simple programming language, I have posted a code below. It is not the most elegant codes, but for a beginner it should do what you're wanting to do. But always try to code it yourself and then come onto SO for clarifying after a few tries.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 20
void frequency(int[][20],int,int);

int main()
{
     int a[MAX][MAX],n,n2,i,j;
     printf("Enter row and column sizes of array: ");//row and column sizes
     scanf("%d%d",&n, &n2);
     printf("\nEnter array: ");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<n2;j++) 
       {
          scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
       }
     }
     frequency(a,n,n2);
     return(0);
}
void frequency(int a[][20],int n, int n2) {
     int i,j,k,c=0,num;
     int x, y,visited[n][n2];
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
       for(j=0; j<n2;j++) {
          c=1;
          num=a[i][j];
          if(visited[i][j]!=1) {
          for(x=0;x<n;x++) {
            for(y=0;y<n2;y++) {
              if((i==x)&&(j==y)) {
                continue;
              }
              if(a[i][j]==a[x][y]) {
                visited[x][y]=1;
                c++;
              }
            }
          }
          printf("\nthe frequency of element %d  is %d",num,c);
          }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually implementing a source code for bitmap image compression using huffman coding. I have successfully generated a two dimensional array of consisting of pixel values of image. the row and column length of my array is approx. 244 each. i have tried your given code in Code Blocks, but failed to get the frequencies of pixels, is it because the array is too big or not i dont know because when i execute the code as a separate program it does give me the output.

Comment: Thank You so much it works perfectly fine. im grateful for your help and support!!!